# Die inverse der Kennlinie: groß oder klein?

Tags: capitalization

Bei folgendem Satz bin ich mir bei der Groß-/Kleinschreibung von `inverse` unsicher:

> Da die Kennlinie bekannt ist, lässt sich deren inverse ermitteln.

Mein Gefühl sagt mir, man müsse hier Großschreibung anwenden, aber die [amtlichen Regelungen](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GrossKlein/pgf57-58.html#pgf58) machen mir einen Strich durch die Rechnung:

> In folgenden Fällen schreibt man Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen klein, obwohl sie formale Merkmale der Substantivierung aufweisen. 1. Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen, die sich auf ein vorhergehendes oder nachstehendes Substantiv beziehen...

Da sich das Adjektiv `inverse` eindeutig auf das vorhergehende Substantiv `Kennlinie` bezieht, muss diese Regel meiner Auffassung nach Anwendung finden. Das Wort `die Inverse` als Substantiv existiert laut canoo.net und duden.de auch nicht. Ließe sich die Großschreibung dennoch rechtfertigen?

Comment: Auch wenn Duden und Co. "die Inverse" nicht kennen, findet man es doch häufig in den entsprechenden mathematischen Definitionen. Für mich ist *inverse* in dem Satz auch kein dekliniertes Adjektiv, sondern das Nomen, und daher eindeutig großzuschreiben.

Comment: @Em1: [answer] - hier ein Link: http://mathe-online.fernuni-hagen.de/MIB/HTML/node67.html - nicht jede gute Antwort muss auch lang sein.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Die Inverse ist ein Nomen.

```
Beispiel:
Gesucht ist die Inverse zur Matrix
```

[Ref. wikipedia.org/wiki/Reguläre_Matrix](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regul%C3%A4re_Matrix)